# can't connect device using socket.io-client, express.js, and react native

Tags: android, express, react-native, socket.io

I built a quick react native project to test using sockets. All I want it to do is have an android device communicate with server and server send something back. I have the express server running on a local port, but I cannot get any devices to connect. [server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYaZq.png)[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCrdW.png)

Comment: Try using the IP address of the machine the server is on rather than `localhost`

Comment: That worked thank you!

Comment: Are you able to run react-native app on Android device by by entering 
`IPaddress:Port` in dev settings?